# Spring autowire the only implementation without defining the bean

Tags: java, spring

I have the following case:

```
@Service
interface OrderingService {

}

public class DefaultOrderingService implements OrderingService {

}

@RestController
public class DefaultOrderingRestController {
    private final OrderingService orderingService;
    public DefaultOrderingRestController(OrderingService orderingService) {
        this.orderingService = orderingService;
    }
}
```

and I would like that Spring autowires the only implementation to the interface by scanning the code. Is this possible?

In other words, currently there are 2 solutions to this issue and I'm asking if there's a third:

1. Move the `@Service` declaration from the interface `OrderingService` to the implementation `DefaultOrderingService`
2. In the Configuration, define the specific Bean as follows:

```
 @Configuration 
 public class DefaultConfig {
      @Bean
      public OrderingService orderingService() {
          return new DefaultOrderingService();
      }
 }
```

QUESTION: Is it possible to have Spring automagically scan (then Spring finds only one implementation of OrderingService) and autowire? If yes, how to do it?
If not, is it not a good practice and why?

Comment: Putting the `@Service` annotation on the interface is wrong, it belongs on the implementation (your solution #1). Solution #2 will also work. Why do you need a third solution? Just pick #1 or #2 and it will work. There is no way to let Spring automatically pick up the implementation if it isn't defined as a Spring bean (by a `@Service` or `@Component` annotation or otherwise in Spring configuration).

Comment: You can make your own component scan and if you find out there's only one implementation of an interface, register it into the application context

Comment: `@Autowired` does that, right? I mean, if there is only one implementation, Spring **autowires** it. Only when there are multiple implementation, Springs throws ambiguity error. And, that's when `@Qualifier` comes into picture. So, why aren't you going with `@Autowired`?

Comment: @RoyalBg interesting suggestion

Comment: No, spring autowires automaticly if there is only one instance. You can have any implementation, but only one instance at runtime, or you have to use either Qualifier of Primary annotation.

Answer (score 1):

i don't know if that posibble or not, but I have a diffirent approach that could be  help:

Add configiration file to hold type of your bean, lets say there are two implementation of `OrderingService` one is `FAKE` and `DEFAULT` in order to have one only in runtime, you have to declare both of beans in project context like below:

```java
@Bean
OrderingService fakeOrderingService() {
  return new FakeOrderingService();
}

@Bean
OrderingService defaultOrderingService() {
  return new DefaultOrderingService();
}
```

If you want one of them, you have to add ConditionalOnProperty like below:

```java
@Bean
@ConditionalOnProperty("app.config.type", havingValue = "FAKE")
OrderingService fakeOrderingService()..

@Bean
@ConditionalOnProperty("app.config.type", havingValue = "DEFAULT", matchIfMissing = true)
OrderingService defaultOrderingService()...
```

`matchIfMissing = true` that will help, if the configuration does not added in your environment, So spring will autowire `defaultOrderingService` in case property missing or if property value is `DEFAULT`, and `fakeOrderingService` if property value is `FAKE`

I hope that will help

Answer (score 0):

The problem with your third solution is that it is dependent on the implementation of the interface . If no corresponding implementation is found , spring would give an error. So i suppose it is definitely not a good practice. Also spring @service annotation is not inherited.
However if you still want to have any alternate solution. You could prefer to define separate beans for the each of the implementation and use a qualifier to get bean from the application context.